# Converting my gear jump bike to a single speed

Tags: restoration

[image]

Hi I’m converting my jump bike to a single speed. I have tried to use the original hub but it is going to be too hard as the chain does not line up and many other things. If I buy this rear hub will this work? And roughly how much should the bike shop cost to relace a 36 spoke wheel?
Thanks 
Jaime

Comment: What is a gear jump bike?    Do you mean a derailleur-equipped bike?

Comment: You should get a price from your LBS to build a wheel.  Very approximately, the labour to build and true a wheel ranges from "equal to the parts cost" up to "double the cost of parts" depending on where in the world you are.  Valuations and costs change over time, and are highly region-dependent, so are considered off-topic.

Comment: Please, post some pictures of your current frame, especially the rear dropouts.

Comment: It's almost always cheaper to buy a new wheel than to pay a shop to replace the hub.

Comment: The hub in picture is a cassette hub

Answer (score 4):

One fairly simple way to convert a derailleur bike to a single speed is to fit a replacement cassette with only one cog.

[image: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61OB0AoUV3L._SX425_.jpg]

Notice this is little more than a stack of spacers, one special cog, and more spacers.  Moving the parts around will let you adjust your chainline inboard or outboard.

The cog is not just one out of a cassette - it has no ramps or pins, and has relatively tall teeth.

Do note that you need to have some way to tension your chain.  For a frame build as single speed it will have either track ends for dropouts, or an eccentric BB, or some other way to adjust the tension.

For your solution you may need to retain the rear derailleur but lock it into one position using the limit screws, and to run it relatively far forward (ie tight) when compared to a multigear config.  EG:

[image: https://www.cxmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/rear-derailleur-as-singlespeed-tensioner_1.jpg]

Comment: You might be able to rough-something up using a butchered cassette, to see if it suits your needs.  Use an old worn cassette as a trial and see if you like the single-speed world enough to spend money on it, or revert to the normal setup if its not to your taste.

Comment: I see that the OP is planning to replace the rear hub anyway. Why not replace it with a flip-flop hub anyway?

Comment: @Mike good idea!  You should totally add that as a new answer, I didn't think of a specific singlespeed hub.   Cost of building a wheel doesn't really vary with what type of hub is used provided spokes are all the same style.   And it gives the choice of two tooth counts.  The dropout style on OPs bike is relevant too - still needs tensioner or trackends.

Comment: thanks, let's wait for some more pictures from the OP, we can then advise about chain tension and other issues they may encounter.